# How to break table across several pages without breaking the row

Tags: longtable, landscape

I'm trying to break a long landscape table across many pages without breaking the row. I saw that we should use `longtable` and landscape packages but it is not working. The code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, left=3.0cm, right=3.0cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
        \begin{landscape}
            \begin{table}
                \scriptsize
                \centering
                \newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[0.08em]}
                \caption{caption name}
                \label{tab:tabsone}
                % *{15}{p{1cm}}
                \begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.7cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{1cm}p{0.7cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{1.6cm}p{1.9cm}@{}}
                    \toprule
                    Study & Cancer & Conditions & Cell Subtype/ Treatment & Patients & Cell Line    & Technique & RNAseq Library & Sequencing Platform & Microarray & Array Platform & Dataset Ids & Publication Citation & Comments & Criteria study inclusion\\ \otoprule
                    A2.2.2 & hsjsjjsj & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & jsjsjsjs & jsjsjsj & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & & & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \midrule
                    O2.h.13 & hshshshs & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & & & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \midrule
                    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \\ \midrule
                    N5.10.2.OP & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & & & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \bottomrule
                \end{longtable}
            \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @TeX.SE thank you :)

Comment: Remove the `table` environment around your `\longtable`. `table` prevents the page break here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contents of a `table` envrionment can't be broken across pages. Hence, remove the `table` environment and move your `\caption` command to inside of `longtable`. (Don't forget the `\\`  after the `\aption` or the `\label`, though). For repeated column headers, use `\endhead` and `\endfirsthead`.

Here is a corrected version of your code. Note though that the table still overflows into the margin on page 2 and 3. This is because page breaks can only happen between table rows not within them. Since your table columns are quite narrow and contain comparably much text, a single table row is taller than the available space. Hopefully the contents of your actual table are shorter.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, left=3.0cm, right=3.0cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
        \begin{landscape}
                \scriptsize
                \newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[0.08em]}
                % *{15}{p{1cm}}
                \begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.7cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{1cm}p{0.7cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{1.6cm}p{1.9cm}@{}}    
                \caption{caption name}             
                \label{tab:tabsone}\\
                    \toprule
                    Study & Cancer & Conditions & Cell Subtype/ Treatment & Patients & Cell Line    & Technique & RNAseq Library & Sequencing Platform & Microarray & Array Platform & Dataset Ids & Publication Citation & Comments & Criteria study inclusion\\ \otoprule \endfirsthead
                 \caption{caption name -- continued from previous page}\\
                    \toprule
                    Study & Cancer & Conditions & Cell Subtype/ Treatment & Patients & Cell Line    & Technique & RNAseq Library & Sequencing Platform & Microarray & Array Platform & Dataset Ids & Publication Citation & Comments & Criteria study inclusion\\ \otoprule \endhead           
                    A2.2.2 & hsjsjjsj & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & jsjsjsjs & jsjsjsj & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & & & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \midrule
                    O2.h.13 & hshshshs & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & & & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \midrule
                    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \\ \midrule
                    N5.10.2.OP & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & & & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \bottomrule
                \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. it solved the problem